# Get the address of a variable in another process

Tags: c++, dll-injection

I have a fairly straight forward goal (it's simplistic because it's just a test), inject a DLL into a hello_world to change what it prints, but without modifying the hello_world.exe to help. The purpose is for me to learn how to similar things to bigger applications that I don't have the source for unlike hello_world.

I have a test.exe that creates the hello_world.exe process and with a remote thread loads the dll library in hello_world.exe. So now the question is what to do with the dll... here's the sources for both the dll and hello_world. I have a Sleep(1000) in the hello_world so that there is a moment for the dll to change the value before it gets printed... but other than that the goal is to change "str" without changing anything in hello_world's source, just the dll.

**The dll:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

void main(){
    //this should be where i somehow get the "str" pointer from hello_world and change it
}

BOOL DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID lpvReserved){
    switch(reason){
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            main();
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Hello world:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

char str[] = "Hello, world";

int main(){
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("%s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Comment: so what is the quesiton?

Comment: you have a process and you have a dll. OK. And now? Do you manually want to load the dll and jump into functions? Replacing something from program which only uses a dll is not possible ( I hope, because that is code injection which is a fat door to enable all kind of viruses to run under the process user rights )because your dll code contains main I believe you have no idea what a dll is?!

Comment: As answer to the headline: You can not get a valid address of a variable in an other process. All addresses are local to the process context. All systems which running with MMU have virtual addresses for each context. So the address itself is useless at all. Maybe you can get a shared memory, but this is also not what you are asking for.

Comment: Well the DLL was loaded in that other process so it is in it's virtual address space, but I need the DLL to get the variable in hello_world to change it. The reason I want to do such a thing is for modding a pc game, but I thought something simple like this would be a simpler start.

Answer (score 2):

**Fortunately** you cannot do that...
Even when [Win32 DLLs are mapped into the address space of the calling process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
  char str[] = "Hello, world";
```

will be flagged by the compiler to be loaded by the loader in a **read-only** memory area then "even" if you manage to get the pointer to the string it won't help you to change its content.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks for the reply. I wanted to do it for this pc game... I've seen dll injection into other games before so I figured it was something like this. I guess I'll try something else....

Comment: Even when hacking a game seems to be fun trust me; in the long run it's always more rewarding ($$) learning "serious" coding skills. Please close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: DON'T.

- It's nearly impossible do do it at all: If you don't have the source code, how do you know the address of the variable? how do you know its size?.
- It's nearly impossible to do it right: How would you test that the original application still works correctly?
- Even if you have the source code, you still need to find out the address of the original variable (something the linker defined once long ago... unless you have the symbol map for your application that's a serious handicap).
- Depending on your operating system you'll get additional pains because the address may change between different calls (if the variable is within a dynamic library)
- You for sure will be the enemy of all virus checkers (messing around with other applications is something viruses do).